# Public attributes and inheritance Java

Tags: java

I'm checking some Java exercises but I'm confused with this one:

We have a Foo class with this structure:

```
public class Foo {
    public int a = 3;

    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
    }
}
```

A Bar class who inherits from Foo:

```
public class Bar extends Foo {
    public int a = 8;

    public void addFive() {
        a += 5;
    }
}
```

And a Test class :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Bar();
        f.addFive();
        System.out.println(f.a);
    }
}
```

I would think the output is 13, but it's 3, my question is Why?..

Comment: The line `int a += 5;` won't compile.  I suspect you meant `a += 5;` to match the code in the superclass method, which needs a semicolon.

Comment: Yep that's right, I was copying on the fly .. thanks ! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to Peter's answer : keep in mind that member variables `are not` polymorphic, so they are not `overriden`. 
I.e. `f.a` still gives you reference to super class's `a` (since `f`'s declared type is `Foo`) whereas `f.addFive()` calls method on `Bar`, (since `f`'s runtime type is `Bar`);

So, for example

```
Bar b = new Bar();
Foo f = b;
f.addFive();
System.out.println(f.a); // prints 3
System.out.println(b.a); // prints 13 as you have expected
```

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 5):

You have two fields, one which *hides*, not replaces the other.  You have `Foo.a` and `Bar.a`  You overridden method alters `Bar.a` but you are looking up `Foo.a`

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't apply to fields.

Answer (score 5):

You need to know that in Java [late-binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java) (mechanism of polymorphism that finds body of method based on actual object at runtime) works **only for methods**, not for fields.

So if you have reference of base type `Foo` that holds object of type derived from Foo like in our case `Bar`

```
Foo f = new Bar();
```

then with `f.field` you will use field from `Foo` class (no polymorphic behaviour here).
But if you use `f.someMethod()` then thanks to late-binding at runtime Java will find and execute code of this method from `Bar` class (since `f` holds insteance of `Bar` object).

So in your code

```
Foo f = new Bar();//you are creating reference of type Foo to instance of Bar
f.addFive();//body of this method will increment `a` declared in `Bar`
System.out.println(f.a);//here you are using `a` declared in Foo.
```

You can get value `a` from `Bar` class if you use reference of type `Bar`.

```
System.out.println(((Bar)f).a);//prints 13.
```

Comment: +1 for `System.out.println(((Bar)f).a);` Makes a good point too.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are initializing a Bar object as a Foo.  You have two choices here, either initialize it as a straight Bar object or add a getter to the Bar object that connects directly to that property.

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.a;
```

or

```
public class Bar extends Foo{
    public int a = 8;

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void addFive(){
        int a += 5;
    }
}

bar.getA();
```

Comment: Why did I get all those down votes for this?  At least write something in response.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Bar#addFive()` method, you declare a local `int a`.  Changes to this local `int a` do not affect the class member `int a`.  Since `f` is a `Foo`, the value of `a` will be `3` in this case.

Also, you do not need to redeclare your `addFive()` method in your `Bar` class since there is no difference from the `Foo#addFive()` method.

EDIT: Oddly, the code you originally posted has changed and the `int a` is now no longer local.  What is the actual code you are using?

Comment: I think that was a typo as that wouldn't compile if it was written that way.

Comment: It will compile even if it is a typo.

Comment: It really won't, try it.